# Getting a sharepoint listitem using GUID in graph api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We need to upload a document to a SharePoint Online list and then add some searchable attributes to the document. We are uploading the document using Microsoft Graph.

Since we need to be able to search for the document against different criteria, we are uploading the document to a List.

Here is a snapshot of the request:

```
string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/" +
    driveID +
    "/items/root:/" +
    fileName +
    ".docx:/content";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage message =
    new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, requestUrl);
message.Headers.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

message.Content = new StreamContent(requestContent);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type",
    "application/json; odata=verbose; charset=utf-8");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
```

When the document gets uploaded we get back the response that includes a GUID and the document name.

```
{
  "createdDateTime": "2018-02-27T10:44:02Z",
  "eTag": "\"{446F157D-ED2C-4C1B-BB3F-56897A6190DA},1\"",
  "id": "01JSWLMSD5CVNHFLHNDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-02-27T10:44:02Z",
  "name": "2018-02-27 15.43.55.7268PM.docx"
}
```

The trick comes when we try to get a hold of that document to add populate the other columns in the List.

We can get the document by using the `id` field of the document in the list but that `id` is not returned as part of the response when we upload the document so cannot use that value for our request.

Our challenge is to get the `ListItem` using the fields that we get back from the JSON response but so far every avenue we have tried has resulted in a failure.

We have tried using both `id` and `name` fields mentioned in the response above but are getting an `HTTP 400` response. Below are the requests we have tried in multiple variations.

```
.../lists/My Library/items?expand=fields&filter=fields/name eq '2018-02-27 15.43.55.7268PM.docx'
```

and

```
...:/lists/My Library/items?filter=id eq '01JSWLMSD5CVXUILHDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2'
```

Where are we losing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the only way we can add an item to a SharePoint List is by adding it as a drive item. Consequently the GUID that we get back is of a drive item and not of a list item. In order to update the list item meta data or to update the fields for the list item you need to get the list item id. Thanks a lot that so far Microsoft maintains the "SharePointIds" resource type for the drive item. What you need to do is search for this resource using the drive drive item GUID that you get after uploading your document and then use the value of "list item" id within the response to update the list item values. Below is the syntax for the request you will make to get the SharePointId of the drive item.

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/MyDriveId/items/MyItemGUID?$select=sharepointids
```

This gave me following response that includes list item id:

```
    {
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('b%21Fxup9FZ-HUOeolxFVUS8xtUFzOnGdmJFmOu-plkSayoX0IRAx4QQLGVWwqhin-F')/items(sharepointIds)/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "\"{B7B82A72-72EF-414A-8C1E-0A26896HDC79},6\"",
"sharepointIds": {
    "listId": "11425fa8-1e03-4010-b195-5b0as83a7f85",
    "listItemId": "1178",
    "listItemUniqueId": "b7b82a72-72ef-414a-8c1e-0a24532ddc79",
    "siteId": "f4a91b17-7e56-431d-9ea2-5c589644bcc6",
    "siteUrl": "https://Mywesite.com/sites/MyLibrary",
    "webId": "e9cc05d5-76c6-4562-98eb-bea33a98742c"
} }
```

Thanks a lot @marc for pointing towards trying the drive id to get a hold of the item using GUID. We are in the green now :)

Comment: This helped me uploading meta information of the newly uploaded file. Is the info regarding getting sharepointid from the GUID anywhere in the Microsoft sharepoint docs?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the `item` you need to include the `id` in in the URL itself:

```
/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items/01JSWLMSD5CVXUILHDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2?$expand=fields
```

I would also suggest using the [Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) instead of rolling your own using `HttpClient`.

Comment: I executed the query as this
`code`
/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items/01JSWLMSD5CVXUILHDNGLWP2WGNNGDEG2?$expand=?fields
`code`
Please note that I removed
`code`
$expand=? 
`code`
from the request because using that with the command was throwing "Bad Request" at us. Now that we use the command as I have mentioned here, we are getting an error stating "Provided list item identifier is not in an allowed format". How would we need to format it to get the item?

Comment: Are you sure that `id` is valid? Can you see the file in the `drive` in the browser?

Comment: The id is what is sent back in the JSON response. I can see the file in the browser. I can even query it through graph using the incremental id that SharePoint assigns it e.g., 1367 etc. I cannot, however, query it using the GUID or the document name, the two elements that I have available once I initially upload the document.

Comment: What do you get back from the `/items` endpoint? Are you able to see the file listed?

Comment: Yes I do see that document listed when I hit the /items endpoint. I do not see the GUID in there though. What I see as an id is the SharePoint list item id "1367". When I query using that id, I can get the document as well. Problem is that I do not know the SharePoint list item id when I upload the document initially.

Comment: If you want I can send you the actual url that we are using to access the document on SharePoint if that can help us troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Any update to the issue? I can see the document in the list, open it and do all sorts of things with it. Is it possible that the GUID is being written/replaced after uploading the document? Is there a way I can see the GUID attached with the document in the list to make sure this is not the case?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the file using the `/drives` endpoint? I'm wondering if this is an issue with how the API looks at a `ListItem` vs. a `DriveItem`.

Comment: I did not try the /drive end point but if it is the case then shall it still be getting the item with /items end point and even with the list item id? What syntax would you suggest to try the/drive endpoint?

Comment: Either `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}` or `/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}`.

Comment: The weird thing is that we can get the item by using itemId, we cannot get it using GUID. When we upload the document, we do not know the itemId because it is sequentially generated by the list. Is there a way to know the GUID of the item? I want to check if the GUID that I get from the response and the one stored in the system are the same.

Comment: We tried using the GUID with the drive end point as you suggested and we are able to get the item. Thanks a lot for the kind help :) Question now is, "How do we update the list item fields?" I think there is a way to get the SharePoint list item id for a drive item but am not sure how to get it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like we can get the List item id if we can grab a hold of "SharePointids" resource type for the drive item. Is it possible? If so how do we get to it?

Comment: It's a property returned by the `DriveItem`.