# How to find GUID of a SharePoint List Item

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint list that contains documents. The list gets populated by pushing documents to it using Graph API. The Graph API creates a GUID when it adds the document to the List. However we are not able to query the list using the GUID that is sent by the Graph API. If we use the GUID as is in the query we get the error

`Provided list item identifer is not in an allowed format`
(The spell error is not my fault, I just copy pasted the message from Graph :)

When I add single or double quotes around the GUID, as suggested by some of the previous posts, it throws the error saying

```
The request is malformed or incorrect.
```

The document is visible in the library and I can query it just fine using the incremental identifier that the list assigns it. I just cannot do it using the GUID and our use case requires us to be able to search the document either by its GUID or by its name both of which we are unable to do using Graph API. In order to further troubleshoot, we need to confirm if the GUID that is being returned by the Graph API is actually the one that is being stored in the SharePoint for the document and if so then what is the format it is being stored in the source system. However all the information that I find on getting the GUID of a list item is dated and none explains how to do it in the context of SharePoint Online. Any help in this regard will help us immensely and will be equally appreciated.

Comment: [I have discussed the answer in the post below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432616/9104165)

Comment: I have discussed the answer to this question in the post below. [How to Find GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432616/9104165)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test result.

Upload:

[image]

Record the returned id.

Query:

URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com,id,id/drives/b!h7fC7DWxPEqE5xE_5o_f6GG9japE3TZKt7zDlyJLOjGQo7SdElHNTrcHpsVjmwMx/items/01CB2EHIYF36RB632I6VDJ3I5UAAGNBFXS
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the example does not work for me if I put the GUID at the end. It works perfectly if I put the list generated id (1367) in the id field. Also the response returned by the server only includes the list item id (1367). It does not include the GUID in the response. However when I upload the document, it only gives me the GUID with its response. Is there a way I can get the list item id instead/in addition of the GUID in my response when I upload the document?